# recursive sql, sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to solve a recursive SQL problem essentially aggregating the status of a group of records.

For the purposes of the question - there are two tables.  One that maintains the aggregation/hierarchy "GROUP_MEMBERS" and one that contains the individual items "ITEMS".

"GROUP_MEMBERS" looks similar (ID being GROUPID, CHILDTYPE being 0 for a group, 1 for individual item, and ID being the child items ID (so groupid for type 0, itemid for type 1)

```
ID | CHILDTYPE | CHILDID

1       0        2
1       1        1
2       1        2
2       1        3
2       1        4
```

In this example, my "ITEMS" table would have only two columns:

```
ID | STATUS

1     0
2     1
3     0
4     0
5     0
```

Effectively what I am trying to do is pull back all "ITEMS", ID and STATUS, under a group recursively (because groups can contain other groups).  So for the example data I provided, if I passed it the GROUPID of 1, it would return ITEMS 1-4 with their statuses; GROUPID 2 would be ITEMS 2-4 with their statuses, etc.

I'm assuming I need to do this via a function and return a table, but I'm not even sure where to begin.

Comment: Do you need the ITEMS per group (like a table valued function) or a total list of ITEMS for all groups?

Comment: Also, do you have only 1 level of recursion, or possibly more?

Comment: There could be more than 1 level of recursion - and I'd prefer to get the ITEMS per group with a TVF I think.  I want to perform some math on the statuses that come back.

Answer (score 3):

This was a nice puzzle, gotta tell ya :)
Hopefully it does you want it to do.

```
DECLARE @GroupRootID INT = 1
DECLARE @GROUP_MEMBERS TABLE (ID int, CHILDTYPE int, CHILDID int)
DECLARE @ITEMS TABLE (ID int, STATUS int)

INSERT INTO @GROUP_MEMBERS VALUES
(1,0,2), (1,1,1), (2,1,2), (2,0,3), (2,0,4), (2,1,3), (2,1,4), (3,1,5), (4,1,5)

INSERT INTO @ITEMS VALUES
(1,0), (2,1), (3,0), (4,0), (5,1)

--              1
--            /   \
--          2     items         items: 1 => 1,1,1
--        / |   \
--      3   4   items           items: 2,3,4 => 2,1,2 - 2,1,3 - 2,1,4
--      |   \   
--    items items               items (3): 5 => 3,1,5
--                              items (4); 5 => 4,1,5

/* Recursivly build the GROUP tree (groups that have subgroups, CHILDTYPE=0), but NOT the lead nodes (CHILDTYPE = 1) */
;WITH GROUP_TREE
AS
(
    /* SELECT all parents */
    SELECT ParentGroups.*, 0 AS LEVEL
    FROM @GROUP_MEMBERS AS ParentGroups
    WHERE ParentGroups.CHILDTYPE = 0
    AND ParentGroups.ID = @GroupRootID

    UNION ALL

    /* SELECT all childs groups for the parents */
    SELECT ChildGroups.*, LEVEL + 1
    FROM @GROUP_MEMBERS AS ChildGroups
    INNER JOIN GROUP_TREE AS Parent ON Parent.CHILDID = ChildGroups.ID
    WHERE ChildGroups.CHILDTYPE = 0
)

/* We now have all groups with their subgroups (not leaf nodes) */
/* Then join the leaf nodes (groups that are no subtree) */
/* Finally union the items from the root node and join the ITEMS to the leaf nodes to get the status */
/* Mind you though that ITEM 5 is linked double and will be returned NON-distinct */

SELECT ITEMS.*
FROM (
    SELECT GROUPS.*
    FROM @GROUP_MEMBERS AS GROUPS
    INNER JOIN GROUP_TREE ON GROUP_TREE.CHILDID = GROUPS.ID
    WHERE GROUPS.CHILDTYPE = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT GROUPS.*
    FROM @GROUP_MEMBERS AS GROUPS
    WHERE GROUPS.CHILDTYPE = 1
    AND GROUPS.ID = @GroupRootID
) AS GROUP_ITEMS
INNER JOIN @ITEMS AS ITEMS ON GROUP_ITEMS.CHILDID = ITEMS.ID
```

Comment: +1 for being one of the best explained answers I've seen in a while.